# python/numpy fastest method for 2d kernel rank filtering on masked arrays (and/or selective ranking)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, median

Given a 2D numpy array

```
MyArray = np.array([[ 8.02,  9.54,  0.82,  7.56,  2.26,  9.47],
           [ 2.68,  7.3 ,  2.74,  3.03,  2.25,  8.84],
           [ 2.21,  3.62,  0.55,  2.94,  5.77,  0.21],
           [ 5.78,  5.72,  8.85,  0.24,  5.37,  9.9 ],
           [ 9.1 ,  7.21,  4.14,  9.95,  6.73,  6.08],
           [ 1.8 ,  5.14,  5.02,  6.52,  0.3 ,  6.11]])
```

and a mask array

```
MyMask =  np.array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
            [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
            [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
            [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
            [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
            [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]])
```

I wish to run a 'holey' median filter that ignores masked elements.

For example, a rank filter with a kernel

```
k = np.array([[ 1, 1, 1],
              [ 1, 0, 1],
              [ 1, 1, 1]]);
```

would run on `MyArray`: sorting the neighbourhood defined by the kernel for each element of `MyArray` and returning the median of only the non-masked elements (averaging if the array is an even number).

Now, currently I am doing this in unpythonic loops, using bottleneck.nanmedian by mapping the mask to NaNs. This is giving me exactly what I need, but I was hoping to rely on 2D array manipulation routines.

`scipy.signal.order_filter` and `scipy.ndimage.filters.rank_filter` are both available (rank_filter appears to be much faster), but it appears they sort `NaN` and `Inf` at the top of the array before returning the rank and biasing the result. It seems neither of these methods support numpy.ma arrays (masking), nor do they accept an array of selective ranks (then I could fill all masks with 0 and offset my rank), nor is there an obvious way to vary the kernel for each location.

I am wondering if I have missed a combination and/or python feature, or if I should be looking to implement a new routine in Cython.

Ignoring boundary handling, the internal points of the above problem would be

```
[[ 0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.   ]
 [ 0.     3.18   3.62   2.26   2.645  0.   ]
 [ 0.     2.74   3.325  2.74   2.64   0.   ]
 [ 0.     3.88   3.62   4.955  6.08   0.   ]
 [ 0.     5.02   5.77   5.77   6.52   0.   ]
 [ 0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.   ]]
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662361/fill-in-missing-values-with-nearest-neighbour-in-python-numpy-masked-arrays?rq=1

Comment: Do you have enough RAM to hold an array of (size data) * (size kernel) ?

Comment: @moarningsun yes, each array is no more than 12mb in memory, I just have to repeat this process a few thousand times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to sacrifice RAM usage to forego the Python loops. I.e. we blow up the original array so that we can apply the filter on all sub-arrays at once. Which is kind of similar to [Numpy broadcasting.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

For an array of 1000x1000 the vectorized function performs roughly 100x faster, in my testing.

In my code I used `NaN`'s for masking, but with some extra lines of code you could also use `numpy.ma` arrays. And I didn't have a `nanmedian` function so I used `nanmean`, performance should be comparable though.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

# test data
N = 1000
A = np.random.rand(N, N)*10
mask = np.random.choice([True, False], size=(N, N))

def filter_loop(A, mask):
    kernel = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]], bool)
    A = A.copy()
    A[mask] = np.nan
    N = A.shape[0] - 2  # assuming square matrix
    out = np.empty((N, N))
    for i in xrange(N):
        for j in xrange(N):
            out[i,j] = np.nanmean(A[i:i+3, j:j+3][kernel])
    return out    

def filter_broadcast(A, mask):
    A = A.copy()
    A[mask] = np.nan
    N = A.shape[0] - 2
    B = as_strided(A, (N, N, 3, 3), A.strides+A.strides)
    B = B.copy().reshape((N, N, 3*3))
    B[:,:,4] = np.nan
    return np.nanmean(B, axis=2)
```

Comment: That is perfect! I am not familiar with stride so I will have to do something reading on this - but it definitely is a speed up.